# Ansible rolling execution block of handlers on targets

Tags: ansible, handler

I have an ansible playbook that calls a role, containing many tasks and handlers. the handlers will be triggered if my desired configuration of service is changed.

What I am looking for is a way to trigger multiple handlers on the hosts sequently. for example, if I have to targets `target1` and `target2` and I have also two handlers `handler1` and `handler2`, What I want in execution of handlers on targets would be something like below:

```yaml
RUNNING HANDLER [myrole : handler 1] ********************************************
changed: [target1]

RUNNING HANDLER [myrole : handler2] *************************************************
changed: [target1]

RUNNING HANDLER [myrole : handler 1] ********************************************
changed: [target2]

RUNNING HANDLER [myrole : handler2] *************************************************
changed: [target2]
```

But as is known, the normal execution of handlers on targets are as below:

```yaml
RUNNING HANDLER [myrole : handler 1] ********************************************
changed: [target1]
changed: [target2]

RUNNING HANDLER [myrole : handler 2] ********************************************
changed: [target1]
changed: [target2]
```

That it is not what I want.

I know that with using of `serial` option in playbook level we can restrict parallelism, but this option will bring the cost of huge time consuming because all of my tasks would be executed in serial as well.

The ways I have tried was using both of `throttle` option and `block` directive on handlers but it wasn't usefull.

Comment: have you explored [flush_handlers](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html#parameter-free_form) of the `meta` module? that can give you more control to trigger the pending actions of the handler at a specific time

Comment: Thanks for recommending the link. I read it and it seems like it doesn't provide any option related to serialize execution of handlers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*flush_handlers*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html#parameter-free_form) on each host separately. Dynamically create and include the file. For example, the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: target1,target2

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: Notify handler1
      changed_when: true
      notify: handler1
    - debug:
        msg: Notify handler2
      changed_when: true
      notify: handler2

    - block:
        - copy:
            dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/flush_handlers_serial.yml"
            content: |
              {% for host in ansible_play_hosts_all %}
              - meta: flush_handlers
                when: inventory_hostname == '{{ host }}'
              {% endfor %}
          delegate_to: localhost
        - include_tasks: flush_handlers_serial.yml
      run_once: true
      when: flush_handlers_serial|d(false)|bool
      
  handlers:

    - name: handler1
      debug:
        msg: Run handler1
    - name: handler2
      debug:
        msg: Run handler2
```

---

by default runs the handlers in parallel (see [*linear strategy*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/linear_strategy.html#ansible-builtin-linear-strategy-executes-tasks-in-a-linear-fashion))

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [target1,target2] ***************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************
changed: [target1] => 
  msg: Notify handler1
changed: [target2] => 
  msg: Notify handler1

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************
changed: [target2] => 
  msg: Notify handler2
changed: [target1] => 
  msg: Notify handler2

TASK [copy] **************************************************************************************************
skipping: [target1]

TASK [include_tasks] *****************************************************************************************
skipping: [target1]

RUNNING HANDLER [handler1] ***********************************************************************************
ok: [target1] => 
  msg: Run handler1
ok: [target2] => 
  msg: Run handler1

RUNNING HANDLER [handler2] ***********************************************************************************
ok: [target1] => 
  msg: Run handler2
ok: [target2] => 
  msg: Run handler2

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************
target1: ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0   
target2: ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

When you enable *`flush_handlers_serial=true`* the file below will be created and included

```yaml
shell> cat flush_handlers_serial.yml 
- meta: flush_handlers
  when: inventory_hostname == 'target1'
- meta: flush_handlers
  when: inventory_hostname == 'target2'
```

This will run the handlers serially, similarly to the strategy [*host_pinned*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/host_pinned_strategy.html#ansible-builtin-host-pinned-strategy-executes-tasks-on-each-host-without-interruption)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e flush_handlers_serial=true

PLAY [target1,target2] ***************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************
changed: [target1] => 
  msg: Notify handler1
changed: [target2] => 
  msg: Notify handler1

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************
changed: [target1] => 
  msg: Notify handler2
changed: [target2] => 
  msg: Notify handler2

TASK [copy] **************************************************************************************************
changed: [target1 -> localhost]

TASK [include_tasks] *****************************************************************************************
included: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-172/flush_handlers_serial.yml for target1

TASK [meta] **************************************************************************************************

RUNNING HANDLER [handler1] ***********************************************************************************
ok: [target1] => 
  msg: Run handler1

RUNNING HANDLER [handler2] ***********************************************************************************
ok: [target1] => 
  msg: Run handler2

RUNNING HANDLER [handler1] ***********************************************************************************
ok: [target2] => 
  msg: Run handler1

TASK [meta] **************************************************************************************************
skipping: [target1]

RUNNING HANDLER [handler2] ***********************************************************************************
ok: [target2] => 
  msg: Run handler2

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************
target1: ok=6    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
target2: ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your best solution. I've got another way of solving this question too. the second way is detailed as one of this question's answers.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a way to solve my problem as a workaround.

the file `handlers/main.yml` would be as below:

```yaml
---
- name: Trigger some handlers sequentially.
  include_tasks: trigger_handlers_sequentialy.yml
  run_once: true
  loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}"
  listen: restart_my_service
```

So, the above handler will connect to just one target (because of using `run_once` option) and the loop operation on the targets will be done one time.

Then, all the handlers that are expected to be run on targets in serial mode should be inserted on the `tasks/trigger_handlers_sequentialy.yml` file:

```yaml
---
- name: handler1
  debug:
    msg: run handler1
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
- name: handler2
  debug:
    msg: run handler2
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
```

So, what will be happened during the playbook execution will be something like below:

```yaml
RUNNING HANDLER [myrole : Trigger some handlers sequentially.] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
included: ~/ansible/roles/myrole/tasks/trigger_handlers_sequentialy.yml for target1 => (item=target1)

RUNNING HANDLER [myrole : run handler1] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [target1]

RUNNING HANDLER [myrole : run handler2] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [target1]
included: ~/ansible/roles/myrole/tasks/trigger_handlers_sequentialy.yml for target1 => (item=target2)

RUNNING HANDLER [myrole : run handler1] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [target1 -> target2(192.168.4.10)]

RUNNING HANDLER [myrole : run handler2] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [target1 -> target2(192.168.4.10)]
```